# Cut the first parameter from PATH string via batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, path

**If I have my path set as follows:**

C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

**I need it to be set as follows:**

C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

**I am using the following code to fetch the first parameter:**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set c=1
for %%A in ("%path:;=";"%") do ( 
set b[!c!]=%%~A
set /a c=c+1
)

echo !%b[1]%!
pause
```

But I cannot seem to find a way to cut the output string from the PATH variable.

Comment: So, which do you want to remove?  "C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA" or the first directory named in the path?

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%path%") do echo %%b`

Comment: @Aacini please send your comment as an answer so that I can close the ticket by marking it as an answer. Its exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The for loop will launch another instance of cmd.exe in the background and isn't necessary to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FOR /F` command is your friend. `tokens` option lets you to take a certain part of a string and optionally to take *the rest* of the string, that is what you want:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims=;" %%a in ("%path%") do echo %%b
```

Further details at any `for /f` description site, like [this one](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know if this is not sufficiently instructive:

```
@setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@set prompt=$G

@set "_literal=test (blah);"
@set "_tmpPath=%_literal%%path%"
@set _tmpPath
set "_tmpPath=!_tmpPath:%_literal%=!"
set _
```

Result:

```
> test
_tmpPath=test (blah);C:\Program Files...SNIPPED...

>set "_tmpPath=!_tmpPath:test (blah);=!"

>set _
_literal=test (blah);
_tmpPath=C:\Program Files...SNIPPED...
```

Cool thing is that if there were more than one "test (blah);" in the path, it would be removed, unless of course it was the last entry and the path didn't have a terminal semicolon.  In which case you first strip the longer version, then the shorter version just to make sure.

Good enough?